# c# Match between two lists, then add up time in between the two lists

Tags: c#, list, compare, addition

I have two lists and a class

```
public class CommonLog
{
    public string Break { get; set; }
    public string Cart { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
}
```

This is list one

```
commonlog.Add(new CommonLog { Break = breakTimeVar, Cart = cartVar,
    Length = lengthHours });
```

and one like this list 2

```
commonlog2.Add(new CommonLog { Break = breakTimeVar2, Cart = cartVar2,
    Length = lengthHours2 });
```

The two pieces of information I need to match are as follows

List 1 contains this

```
0016 009130 00:01:30
```

List 2 Contains this

```
0016 0066486 00:00:30

0016 0050093 00:00:30

0016 0063791 00:00:30
```

I need to match up the first number 0016 between the two lists, and then add up the last numbers 00:00:30 (3 x 30 seconds) from list 2 and compare that total time against list 1 total time, and then make a decision based on if the total of the last numbers (time) from list 2 equal list 1

How would I achieve that?

Comment: Match for everything in list 1 and 2, or just for a specific value?

Comment: And why not store as an int/TimeSpan rather than a string?

Comment: Are there duplicates of the first number in list 1?  If so, do you want to compare the sum from list 2 to each of them?

Comment: I agree with @YairHalberstadt, at the very least if `Length` was a `TimeSpan` then summing it up would be much easier.  As it is you need to parse the values in order to do the sum.

Comment: there are more in the lists so list 1 has this

0036 009130 00:01:30

and List 2 Has 

0036 0063791 00:00:30
0036 0064592 00:00:20
0036 0076290 00:00:50

so on the next loop of list on i want to look for all carts in the 0036 break and add up the times of list 2 that match cart 0036

This data is being read in from two text files. and then stored in a list currently, i am open to doing it a different way, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is a LINQ solution which aggregates your List 2 entries in a similar (but more compact) way of Romoku answer:

```
var groupedLogs = commonlog2
    .GroupBy(c => c.Break, c => TimeSpan.Parse(c.Length))
    // group logs by Break, and get the TimeSpan representation of Length
    // for each entry of the group
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (s, c) => s + c));
    // create a dictionary and aggregate each log group into sums of TimeSpans
```

Then you may iterate through each item of `commonlog` and compare the results:

```
foreach(var log in commonlog)
{
    TimeSpan sum;
    groupedLogs.TryGetValue(log.Break, out sum);
    if(sum == TimeSpan.Parse(log.Length))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Or a one liner way to get only matching entries from `commonlog` (using C# 7 features):

```
var matching = commonlog.Where(
    l => groupedLogs.TryGetValue(l.Break, out TimeSpan v)
         && TimeSpan.Parse(l.Length) == v);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group the individual breaks using [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx) then loop through the aggregate breaks to find matches.

To sum the individual breaks there is [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx).

I recommend using [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) instead of `string` for the `Length`.

Data

```
var totalBreaks = new List<CommonLog>
{
    new CommonLog
    {
        Break = "0016",
        Cart = "009130",
        Length = "00:01:30"
    }
};

var individualBreaks = new List<CommonLog>
{
    new CommonLog
    {
        Break = "0016",
        Cart = "0066486",
        Length = "00:00:30"
    },
    new CommonLog
    {
        Break = "0016",
        Cart = "0050093",
        Length = "00:00:30"
    },
    new CommonLog
    {
        Break = "0016",
        Cart = "0063791",
        Length = "00:00:30"
    }
};
```

Logic

```
//Group the individual breaks by their Break
var breakGroups = individualBreaks.GroupBy(x => x.Break);

// Loop through the aggregates
foreach (var totalBreak in totalBreaks)
{
    // Match the aggregate to the individual
    // The Key is the Break for all individual breaks in the group
    var breaks = breakGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == totalBreak.Break);

    // Do we have a match?
    if (breaks == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var breakLength = TimeSpan.Parse(totalBreak.Length);
    // Add up the individual breaks with Aggregate
    var breakTotal =
        breaks
            .Aggregate(
                TimeSpan.Zero,  // Initial break is 00:00:00
                (time, b) =>    // Add each break to the initial
                    time.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(b.Length)));

    // Does the break length match the total number of breaks?
    if (breakLength == breakTotal)
    {
    }
}
```